# Make a permalink to the most recent blog post

Tags: php, menus, permalinks

I want to make a permalink to my most recent blog post. I would use this link as a navbar link. The reason I'm not putting code straight into the navbar is because I am using a widget which will not let me get into the code, and my coding knowledge is next to none. Could someone ELI5 how to do this and where to insert any php if needed. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Could you also explain how I would implement the PHP code or where I would put it in the WordPress environment.

Answer (score -2):

Use get_posts with `posts_per_page => 1` to get only one latest result. You can than use `get_permalink()` to get the permalink.

```
$args = array(
         'posts_per_page'   => 1,
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order'   => 'DESC',
            ) ;
$latest_posts = get_posts($args);
$permalink = get_permalink($latest_posts[0]->ID);
```

Comment: Please correct your mark-up. Your code is also very error prone. You should also add proper explanation to how your code works and what it actually does. (*As it stands, all it does is breaking reservered global variables*)

Answer (score -2):

You Can just add the tag the_permalink() in the The Wordpress Loop with the  parameters as order:desc inside anchor tags of yours
for example
if you want to display the heading tag as a permalink you just can

">Lorem Ipsum
    } 
} 
?>

Comment: Please see [answer] and also correct your mark-up. Simply dumping code is not a good quality answer

Comment: Please **edit your answer**, and add an explanation to: **why** could that solve the problem?